# Android games on HTC Wildfire

Tags: android, opengl-es

Games like Abduction! World Attack runs at decent speed on HTC Wildfire.

I'm trying to develop a game that can run on all devices even in the HTC Wildfire (that doesn't have a GPU).

I want the game to run as smooth as Abduction! and I was wondering if I should use Canvas or OpenGL ES 1.0...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most definitely want to use opengl-es and maybe pick up the book: Beginning Android Games by mario.

Comment: Even though HTC Wildfire doesn't have a GPU?

Comment: Oh my bad. Then it'll have to be canvas I suppose and I doubt you could develop something comparable to the more decent games out there with canvas but something like abduction MIGHT be possible. The book i'm reading teaches you step by step how to program abduction but it uses opengl-es since that's what the author recommends for good frame rate.